# Unable to Access JBoss Management Panel on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jboss

Hi I currently just setup JBOSS 6.3 EAP on AWS Ubuntu 14.04 Server. I also have Apache installed and running.

The AWS machine has all ports accessible for testing, and no firewall.

Lets say the public IP is: 2.2.2.2

Going to 2.2.2.2 on a web browser gets me to the Apache "It Works!" page.

In terms of JBoss, I run JBoss through standalone.sh.

I get the following lines in the output:
`07:17:02,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
07:17:02,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
07:17:02,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS   7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started in 3621ms - Started 151 of 189 services (56 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)`

I try to visit 2.2.2.2:9990 and am met with a "Webpage not Available" prompt from chrome.

I tried running the command with the -b option: `sudo standalone.sh -b 2.2.2.2`

Then I get this error:
`07:21:40,730 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public
    at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind on 0.0.0.0 instead of 2.2.2.2

The public IP addresses of EC2 instances are not visible on the instance itself.  So, JBoss will not find the network interface with IP 2.2.2.2.

You can try this yourself by issuing the following command :

`ifconfig -a`

You must start your Jboss with

`/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0`

Also, keep in mind that if you want to start the management console, you must

1. create an admin user

`/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh username password --silent`

2. Start JBoss by telling him to start the management interface

`/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Sebastien. Unfortunately I followed your instructions and still I am not able to connect to the :9990 page. "Webpage not available".

Are there any other settings I should be putting?

Comment: Did you open your instance security group to inbound TCP Traffic on port 9990 ? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: Yes, everything is open and there are no firewall rules on the machine.